# Wrap all api response in one object for .net core REST web api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Using .net core API 
I have one response object that I use 
for all responses (POST,PUT DELETE,GET):

```
public class CResponse
    {
        public object d { get; private set; }
        public string ErrorMsg { get; private set; }

        public CResponse(object d, string errorMsg)
        {
            this.d = d;
            ErrorMsg = errorMsg;
        }

        public static CResponse Generate(object d, string errorMsg = null)
        {
            return new CResponse(d, errorMsg);
        }
    }
```

This is how I use it on a POST for example:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]  CCampaignDto campaignAddDto)
    {
CCampaignAdd cCampaignAdd = new CCampaignAdd(campaignAddDto);

        return Created(string.Empty, CResponse.Generate(await cCampaignAdd.SaveChangesAsync()));
    }
```

PUT :

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromBody]  CCampaignDto campaignAddDto)
    {
        CCampaignUpdate campaignUpdate = new CCampaignUpdate(campaignAddDto);

        return Accepted(CResponse.Generate(await campaignUpdate.SaveChangesAsync()));
    }
```

What can I do to wrap all api response with this class
instead of using it on each POST,PUT,DELETE.

Thanks

Comment: @Afshar don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.

Comment: @CodeCaster I usually use `inline code` to highlight technology or class names and similar things. Is this style supposed to be just for code pieces?

Comment: MiddleWares may come to help. They can process every request and response on the server. Also I'm thinking about Filters.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i did it using JsonOutputFormatter

created a custom class:

```
 public class CustomJsonOutputFormatter : JsonOutputFormatter
    {
        public CustomJsonOutputFormatter(JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings, ArrayPool<char> charPool)
            : base(serializerSettings, charPool)
        { }

        public override Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
        {
            var @object = CResponse.Generate(context.Object, (HttpStatusCode)context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode);

            var newContext = new OutputFormatterWriteContext(context.HttpContext, context.WriterFactory, typeof(CResponse), @object);
            newContext.ContentType = context.ContentType;
            newContext.ContentTypeIsServerDefined = context.ContentTypeIsServerDefined;

            return base.WriteResponseBodyAsync(newContext, selectedEncoding);

        }
    }
```

than on startup.cs

```
var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        };

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<JsonOutputFormatter>();
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new CustomJsonOutputFormatter(jsonSettings, ArrayPool<char>.Shared));
        })
```